# Adding to and displaying an array within get_user_meta in Wordpress for tracking login timestamps

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to track login dates/times for Wordpress users.  I want to be able to track the last 10 times the user has logged in. To do this, I need to be able to save an array within user meta.  My code below is not working and I can't figure out why.  I've found multiple other questions on this site that seem to deal with similar subject matter, but their solutions seem to contradict mine.  My code:

```
function drick_track_user_login($user_login, $user) {
$meta_key = 'drick_login_times';
$user_login_meta = get_user_meta( $user->ID, $meta_key, true);
$number_of_timestamps = count($user_login_meta);
if( ! array($user_login_meta) ) {
    $user_login_meta = array();
}
if( $number_of_timestamps < 10 ) {
    $user_login_meta[] = time();
} else {
    array_pop($user_login_meta);
    $user_login_meta[] = time();
}
update_user_meta( $user->ID, $meta_key, $user_login_meta);
}
add_action('wp_login','drick_track_user_login', 10, 2);
```

What I want to happen is when the wp_login action is triggered, the function checks to see how many timestamp values are in the 'drick_login_times' array.  If it's over 10, to delete the last one then add in the newest time.

I've seen on multiple answers that if you don't have "true" for the third parameter in the get_user_meta function, it will create nested arrays (which I've seen happen). However, if I set that to "false" then I get a 500 Server error when logging in, and the WP_DEBUG log shows:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings
```

So I must be misunderstanding how this should work. I want the meta data to be an array, but I need the get_user_meta to be true - and the get_user_meta codex says false will return an array - which causes the nested array problem. Another answer has the conditional statement to make sure it's an array:

```
if( ! array($user_login_meta) ) {
    $user_login_meta = array();
}
```

But that doesn't seem to help the server error on login. Could someone show me what is incorrect in the code, and/or point me to an answer that I missed? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting error because of this line:

```
if( ! array($user_login_meta) ) {
```

Here you're just creating `array` with function [array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) without saving it's stage in some variable. So, you will never reach this line `$user_login_meta = array();`.

Here is working code:

```
function drick_track_user_login($user_login, $user)
{
    $meta_key = 'drick_login_times';
    $user_login_meta = get_user_meta($user->ID, $meta_key, true);
    $number_of_timestamps = count($user_login_meta);

    if (!is_array($user_login_meta)) {
        $var[] = $user_login_meta;
    }else{
        $var = $user_login_meta;
    }

    if ($number_of_timestamps < 10) {
        $var[] = time();
    } else {
        array_shift($var);
        $var[] = time();
    }

    update_user_meta($user->ID, $meta_key, $var);
}

add_action('wp_login', 'drick_track_user_login', 10, 2);
```

We checking, if we got `array` with function [is_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php), and if not, then creating it( will work when user first time loged in ). In other cases we'll use `$var = $user_login_meta;`.

Also, with [array_pop()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) you're removing the last log of users loged in. I think, you should delete the first one with [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I came to a very similar conclusion, the only difference being for my conditional statement I had if the meta data was empty, to add_user_meta with the first timestamp as an array. My "else" was the same as yours. Once I got that working, I realized that array_pop was not the function I needed and used array_shift as you suggested.  The only other thing was to use "current_time()" instead of time() to get my local timestamp instead of UTC. Since you put this answer in quicker and more succinctly than I ever could, I marked yours as correct.  Thank you again!